# when I start OfficeWriter of Libreoffice, it spins for a minute and then quits

Tags: libreoffice

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 from a flash drive. I have tried purging and reinstalling Libreoffice but I still get the behavior. Running dmesg tells me:

```
 audit: type=1400 audit(1608660837.106:8200): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="usr/share/drirc.d" pid=50658 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=999 ouid=0
```

Comment: What happens if you run it from a terminal window (xterm)? Did you try to rename your profile folder befure running LO? Did it work previously? If yes - what changed?